# How to return html code in a javascript function with conditional statements with select onchange

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, function

by selecting the option it has to return the html tags

```
<select onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="none" selected>none</option>
    <option value="1">Blood Group</option>
    <option value="2">Donor name</option>
</select>



<script>
function getval(sel)
{
 if (sel == 1) {
        return '<label for="Bloodgroup">Blood Group</label>
         <select name="bg"  class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
           <option value="O+" selected>O+</option>
           <option value="O-">O-</option>
           <option value="A+">A+</option>
           <option value="A-">A-</option>
         </select>';
    }else if (sel == 2) {
        return ' <label for="name">Name</label>
         <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control" required>';
   }
}
</script>
```

I want an output by choosing the options
for example: if the option is selected as bloodgroup
[image]

else if it is donor name

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues in your code. Firstly the argument you're passing to the `getval()` function is the `select` element reference, not the value which was selected, so the `if` condition needs to read the `value` property from the argument.

In addition your `return` statements in the function won't do anything alone, as nothing is done with the values you provide back from the function. To add the HTML in the strings to the DOM you need to call a function or property of a target element to append the content to. In the following example that's done using `querySelector` and `innerHTML` respectively:

```js
let content = document.querySelector('#content');

function getval(el) {
  if (el.value == 1) {
    content.innerHTML = `<label for="Bloodgroup">Blood Group</label>
         <select name="bg"  class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
           <option value="O+" selected>O+</option>
           <option value="O-">O-</option>
           <option value="A+">A+</option>
           <option value="A-">A-</option>
         </select>`;
  } else if (el.value == 2) {
    content.innerHTML = `<label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control" required>`;
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getval(this);">
  <option value="none" selected>none</option>
  <option value="1">Blood Group</option>
  <option value="2">Donor name</option>
</select>

<div id="content"></div>
```

However it's also worth noting that using inline event handlers in `onclick` attributes is no longer good practice. In addition, storing HTML within your JS should be avoided. A more modern solution would be to use an unobtrusive event handler and have all the HTML within the DOM when the page loads and simply toggle its visibility.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's an example of how to do that:

```js
let content = $('#content');

$('select').on('change', e => {
  $('.toggle').hide().filter(`.${e.target.value}`).show();
});
```

```css
.toggle { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="none" selected>none</option>
  <option value="bloodgroup">Blood Group</option>
  <option value="donor">Donor name</option>
</select>

<div id="content">
  <div class="toggle bloodgroup">
    <label for="Bloodgroup">Blood Group</label>
    <select name="bg" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option value="O+" selected>O+</option>
      <option value="O-">O-</option>
      <option value="A+">A+</option>
      <option value="A-">A-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle donor">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
```